# Method to know the Unity version of an Unity project?

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a way of knowing the Unity version used to make an Unity project?
Before it was possible checking the beginning of the Projectsettings file with an hex editor, but now nothing is shown about it. Any clues?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@DavidGuaita
Its simple you can find unity version by doing this simple trick

GOTO Your Project > Library
Here you will see lots of files with .asset format open any of them in notepad.

In notepad editor you can see the unity version in first line

Source **[Know the Unity version of a Unity project](http://unity3diy.blogspot.com/2014/12/know-unity-version-of-unity-project.html)**

Comment: Thanks you find it helpful and I find it [here](http://unity3diy.blogspot.com/2014/12/know-unity-version-of-unity-project.html)

Answer (score 3):

You can use preprocessor directives

```
#if UNITY_4_5
Debug.Log("this is Unity 4.5");
#endif
```

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/PlatformDependentCompilation.html

Comment: Thanks, but that define depends of the Unity version you are using, not the project's version. The version will be upgraded or downgraded to meet the Unity's version, but I would like to know if there is a way of identifying the project's version even without opening it.